# server cache js and css? clean history does not solve

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have one server that when I change some file in FTP it takes a while until I can see it in browser.

I clean history, restart browser, clean again and the old version of my css/js still there. Press f5, shift f5, shift r... nothing works. it takes about 5 minutes to change.

Is it any php.ini, apache config, htaccess or something?

Comment: Maybe a proxy cache somewhere. CSS and Javascript files should be visible immediately. You may also search for `Expires*` directives in your Apache config files (look for 5 minutes/300 seconds).

Answer (score 1):

Add Versioning to your *.css and *.js files, this should solve all your nightmares ;)

Seriously, are you able to reload apache after submitting changes through FTP?

`sudo service apache2 reload`
or
`apachectl -k graceful`